# Adding business logic to JPA entities

Tags: jpa, domain-driven-design, anemic-domain-model

Having the next scenario, where I have to apply some static filters with JPA specifications(add WHERE clauses) to a JPA entity to get a list of dogs filtered for example, I receive an id from an entity and I have to apply the same filters but send error messages for each filter not accomplished. For example: having entity Dog, I receive an id, get this entity with JPA and apply some filters like dog age>3 years, etc...

My idea is to reuse the JPA specifications in order to do it but using them will not give me information about why I am not getting the entity and which filter has been not accomplished in order to send the error message.

What I have done is to add methods like isDogOlderThan3Years() to the JPA entity and the entity itself asks for its attributes and so on for each of the filters. I think it has to do with non anemic entities. Is this a good/bad solution? Is there a better one?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you're trying to find a list of dogs that's older than 3 years.
If that's the case, this is just a query and should not be part of your domain model.

Comment: But I mean with more than one filter, not just one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [specification pattern](https://martinfowler.com/apsupp/spec.pdf) could be useful here.

You could use the [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) to translate specification compositions to JPA queries and you could implement the `remainderUnsatisfied` operation discussed in the above article to find out which criterias were not met by a given candidate.

If you do not care about separation of concerns, you can implement `toJpaFilter`, `describe`, etc. methods directly on the specifications
.

I've used that approach in a project of mine where I managed to reuse the same specifications to do the following and it worked pretty well:

- define complex access control rules & filters
- define & enforce business rules
- generate user-friendly descriptions of the specifications

Comment: Why not add @Transients methods like isDogOlderThan3Years() to the JPA entity?. Its what DDD talks about rich models, right?

Comment: @user3254515 Rich model doesn't mean putting all responsibilities in a single entity. Specifications would be enriching your model as well and would be more flexible that if all the predicate logic is within the entity itself.

Comment: Ok, so about "and you could implement the remainderUnsatisfied operation", I could create a class named DogOlderThan3YearsSpecification that receives a Dog as a parameter and returns boolean. The implementation of this method would ask for the age of the Dog object. Is this the idea right? This way you dont have to modify the JPA entity(not violating the OPEN/CLOSE principle) and for more future Specifications, you just should create a new Specification, right?

Comment: Yes exactly. I wouldn't be that specific though, keep specs a bit more open such as `DogOlderThan` and then you can specify the time-frame for instance. E.g. `new DogOlderThan(Duration.ofYears(3))`. Then you can implement composite specifications such as `AndSpec` and `OrSpec`, etc. to compose those into more complex ones.

Comment: Perfect!. What package woud you allocate these custom Specification classes?

Comment: @user3254515 Anywhere within the domain. If they are `Dog` specifications then I believe within the `dog` package or `doc.spec` perhaps. Now like I said, if you care about separation of concerns & layering, you could implement the visitors in the infrastructure... e.g. `JPATranspilerDogSpecVisitor`